# SelectOneMenu disable from javascript

Tags: javascript, jsf

I am usuing JSF-primeface and javascript.

Here it is the code of javascript.

```
<script>
var $element = $("select['se:type5'] option:selected").val();

alert($element);

var input = document.getElementById('se:search');
var combo = document.getElementById('se:type1');

if($element == 1)
{
    input.disabled = false; 
    combo.disabled = true;
}
else if($element == 2)
{
    input.disabled = true; 
    combo.disabled = false;
}
</script>
```

I can disable the inputbox usuing the above code but onemenu does not effected.

Here is my JSF code

```
      <p:selectOneMenu id="type5"  effect="fold" onchange="disabled();" 
                               required="true" 
                               label="Type5"  styleClass="select-option" style="border:1px solid #b5b5b5; padding-left:5px; margin-top:5px;width:298px;height:25px;" >

        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Search By Skill" itemValue="1" />  
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Search By Location" itemValue="2" />  



              </p:selectOneMenu> 
       <p:inputText value="#{user.latitude}" id="latitude" style="visibility: hidden" />
  <h:panelGrid columns="4">







      <p:inputText id="search" styleClass="inner-page-input-type"

         onfocus="if(this.value=='Job title, Skills, Company, etc.') this.value='';" 
 onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Job title, Skills, Company, etc.';" type="text"  
 value="#{user.skill}"   >  

        </p:inputText>  


      <p:selectOneMenu id="type1" value="#{user.geoLocationLatitude}" effect="fold" 
                               required="true" 
                               label="Type1"  styleClass="select-option" style="border:1px solid #b5b5b5; padding-left:5px; margin-top:5px;width:298px;height:25px;" >

        <f:selectItem itemLabel="---km---" itemValue="1" />  
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Under 150km" itemValue="150" />  
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Between 150km - 300km" itemValue="300" />  
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Between 300km - 450km" itemValue="450" />  
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Between 450km - 600km" itemValue="599" /> 
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Above 600km" itemValue="600" /> 

              </p:selectOneMenu>
```

```
 </h:form>
```

Comment: JavaScript doesn't care if you're using JSF, Python, or PHP. It only cares about the HTML, that said, I'd suggest posting the raw HTML instead of your JSF code. On a related note, I don't see any elements with an `id` of `se:search` or `se:type1`.

Comment: @AymanSafadi: it are the JSF-generated IDs of `<p:inputText id="search">` and `<p:selectOneMenu id="type1">`. The `se` is the ID of their form `<form id="se">`.

Answer (score 5):

JavaScript knows *nothing* about the JSF code. Instead it knows everything about its generated HTML output. Look at the generated HTML output by rightclick page in browser and *View Source*. If you look closely, you'll see that the `<p:selectOneMenu>` doesn't generate a `<select><option>`, it instead generates a `<div><ul><li>`. The `disabled` attribute is only supported on `<select>`. Hence you don't see any effect.

I suggest you to disable the thing via JSF ajax instead of via JavaScript. It's a matter of adding a `<f:ajax>` or `<p:ajax>` inside the dropdown and specifying the IDs of components which needs to be updated wherein the `disabled` check is been done based on the currently selected item. No need for JavaScript boilerplate anymore. This way you'll also take advantage of the robustness of server side validation.

```
<p:selectOneMenu binding="#{searchType}" ...>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Search By Skill" itemValue="1" />  
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Search By Location" itemValue="2" />  
    <p:ajax update="search type1" />
</p:selectOneMenu> 

<p:inputText id="search" ... disabled="#{searchType.value == 2}" />  

<p:selectOneMenu id="type1" ... disabled="#{searchType.value == 1}">
    ...
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

---

By the way, the variable name "combo" is wrong. It's a dropdown, not a combobox. A combobox is an **editable** dropdown. The `<p:selectOneMenu>` doesn't render an editable dropdown, but just a dropdown.

Answer (score -1):

Going on what you said, try this instead:

```
var input = document.getElementById('search');
var combo = document.getElementById('type1');
```

Comment: You're confusing jQuery with JavaScript (and not understanding what the OP is actually asking).